# É possível programar para web com Lua?

Tags: aplicação-web, lua

Vejo muitos tutoriais na internet que assimilam a utilização da linguagem `Lua` ao desenvolvimento de jogos.

Mas gostaria de saber o seguinte:

- É possível desenvolver para web utilizando a linguagem `Lua`?
- Existe algum framework que possa possibilitar isso?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sem dúvida nenhuma, qualquer linguagem pode. Mesmo que houvesse alguma dificuldade no atual ecossistema, e é bom deixar claro que não tem, poderia ser estendido com C para dar esta capacidade. Claro que ela não tem tudo tão prontinho quanto PHP ou outras linguagens. Não existem *frameworks* tão completos quantos estas outras linguagens (o que pode ser uma vantagem), mas tem alguma coisa pronta.

Veja o [módulo Lua para o Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_lua.html).

[Módulo para Ngnix](http://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module).

[Extensão para IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2015/06/iislua-for-iis-7x).

[Acesso por CGI](http://keplerproject.github.io/cgilua/).

Kepler é um maduro [projeto para este objetivo](https://github.com/keplerproject).

[Orbit](http://keplerproject.github.io/orbit/) é um *framework* MVC.

[Sailor](https://github.com/Etiene/sailor) é outro.

Existem diversos outros.

[Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_web_programming.htm).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 13):

Sim. não é um ecossistema muito maduro, mas existem opções de frameworks web em Lua:

- [**Lapis**](http://leafo.net/lapis/)
- [**Sailor**](http://sailorproject.org)
- [**Orbit**](http://keplerproject.github.io/orbit/)
- [**Ophal**](http://ophal.org)

Lapis e Sailor parecem mais avançados e robustos, além de mais recentes e atualizados.

Answer (score 5):

Sim é possível.

Você pode usar o [Orbit](http://keplerproject.github.io/orbit/), ele é um framework MVC para a web.

Answer (score 3):

Sim! 
Lista de frameworks por categoria:

Microframework: Lapis

MVC: Sailor, Orbit

Event-driven: Luvit, TurboLua

CMS, Wikis e outros: Ophal, LuaPress, Sputnik, Tir, Lusty, Moonstalk, Webmcp, Mercury, Vanilla, Gimlet Cocktail, bamboo

No Lua.Space eu fiz um post com reviews de vários desses:
http://lua.space/webdev/the-best-lua-web-frameworks

(Eu queria ter postado a url pra cada framework aqui mas minha reputação no stackoverflow não deixa mais de 2 por enquanto :( )

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta para a pergunta primária:**

Se Lua está dentro de uma string pode ser interpretada e transformada em [Abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), então depois a árvore do código pode ser transformada em uma string que apresenta um código funcional para JavaScript/HTML5. Então, sim. É possível.

*Ferramentas para conversão de Lua para linguagens interpretadas da Web passariam por isso:*

**Texto (Lua)** > **Interpretação** & **geração de árvore** > **Compilação para Web**

- Eu creio...

Atualmente já existe parser para Lua que retorna a **Abstract syntax tree** do texto. Você pode achar no Github ou vasculhando as páginas de pesquisa através do Google.